# Undefined file in javascript array when grabbing files from an input type="file" tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html5-filesystem

I have this really weird issue while grabbing images from an input tag, and I can't figure out why. Here's the code:

```
var files,
    fileCounter = 0,
    fileArray = [];

$("#fc").on("change", function() {
    files = $("#fc")[0].files;
    console.log(files);
    for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
        fileArray[fileCounter] = files[fileCounter];
        fileCounter++;
        console.log(fileArray);
    }
});
```

The html is pretty simple:

```
<input type="file" id="fc" multiple="multiple" />
```

The fileArray should be grabbing each image as I add it, but it will only grab 2 before listing files as "undefined". No clue why.

Comment: what is meant by alert.log????

Comment: try doing files = $("#fc").get(0).files[0];

Comment: @JqueryKing That meant to be a console.log, I don't even know how that got changed.

Comment: @man_luck That wouldn't work. $('identifier')[0].files is the proper way to grab the files using jquery, and like I said, it works fine until it gets past 2 files. It's still grabbing data, it just can't tell what it is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue you are having on subsequent additions to `fileArray` stems from your index value in the assignment:

```
fileArray[fileCounter] = files[fileCounter];
```

Because `fileCounter` is essentially the length of the `fileArray`, after the first loop any subsequent additions would cause `fileCounter` to start at values greater than 0. Therefore when you tried to assign `files[fileCounter]` to the `fileArray`, the index you were selecting was greater than 0 which for a single file array would mean you were referencing an undefined element.

That said, you don't really need those counters but just the array:

```js
var fileArray = [];

$("#fc").on("change", function() {
  var files = $("#fc")[0].files;
  console.log(files);
  for (var i = 0, len = files.length; i < len; i++) {
    fileArray.push(files[i]);
    console.log(fileArray);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="file" id="fc" multiple="multiple" />
```

You could even simplify this further by using `concat` and `slice`:

```js
var fileArray = [];

$("#fc").on("change", function() {
  var files = $("#fc")[0].files;
  console.log(files);
  // convert `files` to an array and concat it to `fileArray`
  fileArray = fileArray.concat(Array.prototype.slice.call(files));
  console.log(fileArray);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="file" id="fc" multiple="multiple" />
```

Comment: The issue with this is that I need to hold the files on a longer term basis, and "i" will keep resetting to 0, replacing what was in that spot in the array. The code I have does actually work until fileCounter hits 2, which is when it starts saying that it is pulling undefined data. I apologize if none of this was clear from my original question.

Comment: @TylerSears This solution does work. `fileArray` will retain all selected files meanwhile the temp `files` is only used while pushing the newly selected files onto `fileArray`. You can try the solution out by clicking "Run code snippet".

Comment: You are correct, I just read your code wrong. My apologies. Thank you for the solution!